# How can i change status to 'ingedient'

Tags: python, django

I want to change status from 'Niet ingedient' to 'ingedient' with a button click. 
I have created a script but I keep getting an error.
Does someone know how I can fix this error?

Error:

```
Reverse for '<WSGIRequest: GET '/weekstaat/indienen/26'>' not found.
'<WSGIRequest: GET '/weekstaat/indienen/26'>' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

view.py

```
    def indienen(request, id):
        global Weekstaat
        weekstaat = Weekstaat.objects.get(pk=id)
        Weekstaat.status = 'Ingedient'
        weekstaat.save()
        return redirect(request, 'weekstaat/index.html')
```

-model

```
    class Weekstaat(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False, blank=False)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='Niet ingediend',)
        jaar = models.ForeignKey(Jaar, default=datetime.now().year, null=False, blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        week = models.ForeignKey(Week, default=date.today().isocalendar()[1], null=False, blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        werknemer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='weekstaat_werknemer', null=False, blank=False, default=1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        maandag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
        dinsdag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
        woensdag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
        donderdag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
        vrijdag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
        zaterdag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
        zondag = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.jaar) + ' week ' + str(self.week) + str(self.werknemer) + str(self.status)
```

-html

```
    <td class="text-center">
                    <a href="{% url 'weekstaat-indienen' Weekstaat.id  %}">
                      <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="bevestigIndienen()">indienen </button>
                    </a>


                  </td>
                  <td class="text-center">
                      <button type="button" class="read-Contract btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-id="{% url 'read_Weekstaat' Weekstaat.id %}">
                        <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
                      </button>
                      <button type="button" class="update-Contract btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-id="{% url 'update_Weekstaat' Weekstaat.id %}">
                        <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
                      </button>
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            {% else %}
              <p class="text-primary">U heeft nog geen Weekstaat</p>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

{% endblock content %}

{% block extrascripts %}
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function bevestigIndienen(){
        if(confirm('U staat op het punt een weekstaat in te dienen. Weet u het zeker?') != true){
            document.getElementById('formulierIndienen').action = '';
            window.location.href = "{% url 'home' %}";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean `render`, not `redirect`.

(But note, you shouldn't really be changing statuses on a GET request. Your form should submit a POST request, and your view should then redirect to another URL after processing the submission.)